# Windows store app messageDialog - proceed when close

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I wish to achieve that program will not proceed to next line in code until user click `close` button on `messageDialog`. Is that possible?

In this example I wish to change document background color to red until user click `close`. After this it will go back to white background. So I wish to have red color of backround only when messageDialog is active/visible/shown.

```
Globals["messageDialog"]("Something went wrong!", "#FF0000");

WinJS.Namespace.define("Globals", {
    messageDialog: function (string) {
        Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(string).showAsync();
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, the `showAsync()` returns a promise which completes only when the user closed the dialog. So just write something like

```
Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(string).showAsync().done(function () {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use Await keyword

`await  Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(string).showAsync();`